# Meaning of "raised structure" in microwave networks

Tags: rf, power-electronics, electromagnetism, transmission-line, microwave

Can you help me to understand what "raised structure" means and why it determines the following property of the S matrix?

[image]

[image]

Reference: [here.](http://arpg-serv.ing2.uniroma1.it/mostacci/didattica/lab-elettronica-I/LezioneDD_matriceS/03_Excercise_MatrixCalculus_2019.pdf)

Comment: huh, never heard of that. Honestly, that might be a translation mistake; if we think assumed "raised" is *rialzato*, maybe someone misunderstood *reale* (as in the opposite of *immaginaria*) when translating? I know it's far-fetched, but the best I can think of.

Comment: It appears to be saying that all the power that comes in goes out. I don't know why that would be called "raised structure". Perhaps they are saying that no power couples to other nearby objects, because it's hanging up in the air and there are no nearby objects?